# CakePHP session refreshes at each request

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm working on my first app w/ CakePHP 2.3 and I'm having an issue where I can login (no auth errors), but my session isn't sticking around so I'm sent back to the login page when the `Auth->redirect()` is called. I'm sure I'm just missing a setting or have something configured slightly wrong, but I haven't been able to find it.

```
# core.php
# session record is written the the database, but the same record's id changes w/ every request
Configure::write('Session', array(
  'defaults' => 'database',
));

Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

I've tried tweaking the various `Session.X` parameters, but nothing has made any difference. I'm using bcrypt authentication with the following settings in my `AppController`:

```
'Auth' => array(
  'authenticate' => array(
    'Blowfish' => array(
      'fields' => array( 'username' => 'email' ),
      'scope'  => array( 'active' => '1' )
    ),
  ),
  'authorize' => array( 'Controller' ),
  'loginAction'    => array( 'admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login' ),
  'loginRedirect'  => array( 'admin' => true, 'controller' => 'activities', 'action' => 'index' ),
  'logoutRedirect' => array( 'admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login' ),
),
```

What piece am I missing?

**UPDATE**

Realizing that this is only happening in my dev environment, I compared my Cake config (database, core, bootstrap) and php.ini values -- no differences. I'm stumped.

Comment: No redirection in, perhaps, the users_controller?

Comment: Nope, the redirect is happening.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I am redirecting to the homepage (/) which routes to `/admin/activities/index`. A debug immediately before the actual redirect verifies that I should be going where I expect.

Comment: Are you positive it's the session that gets deleted and not that you doesn't have authorization to enter a page so it redirects you?

Comment: @Nunser - It's not that the session gets deleted. I'm working locally and saving sessions to the db. When I first enter, I get a session record. When I login, I still have one session record, but the ID is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy Headslap, Batman.

So here's the issue. I'm storing sessions in the database. Somewhere, somehow, an (obviously) automated process changed the `cake_sessions.data` field to `cake_sessions.DATA`. Although I've looked at the database a thousand times while debugging this, I *just* noticed that difference.

Problem solved.

Moral of the story: Developers, don't let your database field names grow up and change case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set 'Session' as a component too.

Comment: It's there. I probably should have included my entire `$components` array set in `AppController` in the original question, but the `Session` component is there.